# is there a way to manually step / scrub a CAAnimation?

Tags: ios7, core-animation

I'm using a UIKit dynamics for animating a UIView. As the `UIView` is dragged (responding to physics and whatnot), the background view (it's superview) needs to fade out and some `UILabel` needs to fade in. So far, I've gotten away with doing this by adding a block to the appropriate `UIDynamicBehavior` and manually go about decreasing the superview's alpha and increasing the `UILabel's` alpha. This works fine as long as I want a linear crossfade, that is: superview(1 - a) + label(a).
But actually, my animation needs to be a bit more involved. Something along the lines of:

1. The superview starts fading out, say up to .2 alpha
2. At this point the label starts fading in at a greater pace (different timing function if you will).
3. At the end of the animation, the superview is at alpha = 0 and the label at alpha = 1.

Sure, I could just compute this into a formula and manually update the alpha values according to that. But I was wondering if there is a way I could create a CA animation group or CATransaction with a few animations, apply this to the appropriate layers and then step thru the frames in the action block of the dynamic behavior.

For instance, the `CAMediaTiming` protocol has `timeOffset` which can be used to start the animation offset in time. I'm thinking something similar but that would essentially keep the animation "paused" at all times and I could just tell it to jump to (interpolate) a specific point in time. I'm not sure, however, if there is any such property (like `timeOffset`) or way to do it.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18683845/608157)?

Comment: exactly that! Hadn't seen that answer before. Good to know it works!