# animated by percentage before iOS 7

Tags: ios, animation

`UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` is a transformation available in iOS 7. Is it possible to implement `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` prior iOS 7?

For Example, can I do the same updating percentage of animation when using `CAAnimation` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in iOS 6?

UPDATE:
I can follow panGesture to updating percentage of animation, and finish the whole animation after my finger up:

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [self.transitionView.layer timeOffset];
self.transitionView.layer.speed = 1.0;
self.transitionView.layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
self.transitionView.layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [self.transitionView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
self.transitionView.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

But if I wanna to cancel the animation, how should I do? 
My idea is setting `autoreverses` to yes, and calculating `timeOffset` to what I expect. For example, animation duration is 1s, and total time is 2s, if I want to revers animation when timeOffset is 0.5, the same status at reverse progress is 1.5. This is my code and it did not work:

```
self.animation.autoreverses = YES;
self.transitionView.layer.timeOffset = 2 - percent; // duration is 1s, percent is current time offset
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [self.transitionView.layer timeOffset];
self.transitionView.layer.speed = 1.0;
self.transitionView.layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
self.transitionView.layer.beginTime = 0.0;

CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [self.transitionView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] -  pausedTime;

self.transitionView.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what [I wrote about animation timing](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/) and scroll down to "Controlling animation timing". There is an [accompanying example on GitHub](https://github.com/d-ronnqvist/blogpost-codesample-PullToRefresh) that uses scroll events to manually drive an animation from the scroll events.

You can use the same technique (setting the timeOffset on the layer) with a gesture recognizer to drive the animation.

There is also a much simpler example [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683845/608157) that uses a slider and its action to control the animation.

Comment: Yes, I am considering timeOffset is key point, I will check out your example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I update my question, do you have any idea how to cancel the animation?

Comment: @codiction You can always remove the animation and add another animation from the current presentation layers value back to the original value. You don't have to interact with this animation so remember to set the speed of the layer back to `1.0` between cancelling the manual animation and adding the going-back animation.

Comment: You mean I just make another animation to go back to origin place, Yes, it works. have any method to just rollback original animation which added at first time?

Comment: You can play it backwards by setting `speed = -1.0` but you have to make sure that it is removed when it reaches the "beginning" :D (If the smiley didn't make it obvious: this is mostly fun to play around with but I wouldn't recommend it as a serious solution. I would use another animation going back)

Comment: You mentioned this method in your article, I have already tried this, but it did not perform any animation, the view disappeared immediately.

Comment: @codiction Oh yeah, setting speed = -1 on the layer has some side effects, but setting it to -1 on the animation (before adding) works as expected. I could have been more clear about that. You can get rid of some of the side effects by setting a fillMode, etc. on the layer but it's mostly a mess.