# Animate image with gesture

Tags: ios, animation, bezier

I've created an animation of a plane moving along a bezier path. Is there a way to start the animation when a user swipes a certain direction? (i.e if the user pans right, the plane moves right along the path. if the user pans left, the plane moves left along the path).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to start the animation when the user swipes or do you want to drag the image along the path?

Comment: Pretty much drag along the path. So if the user stops the gesture, but is still pressing, the image stays at that spot on the curve.

Comment: Actually dragging along the path or just controlling it with a horizontal movement (sort of like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375822/tweening-interpolating-between-two-cgpaths-uibeziers/18683845#18683845))?

Comment: A little more detail: I am using a scroll view. When the user scrolls from the first page to the second page, I was going to implement this animation. (i.e there will be a cartoon iphone in the middle of the scrollview. When the user pans to the second page, a paper airplane will fly from the iphone on the first page to the iphone on the second page.)

Comment: In that case you can use the offset in `-scrollViewDidScroll:` to drive the timeOffset of the animation.

Comment: Will that work with a CAKeyFrameAnimation? Or do I use a CABasicAnimation?

Comment: Both will work just fine.

Comment: When you've written something that solves your problem, please come back and post it as an answer to your question (and mark it as the accepted answer). This way, others who have the same problem can find the question and the answer can help them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curve Setup:

```
self.trackPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
self.trackPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:P(self.scrollView.center.x,self.scrollView.center.y-20)
                               radius:110
                           startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(70)
                             endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(115)
                            clockwise:NO];


self.plane = [CALayer layer];
self.plane.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0, 60.0);
self.plane.position = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.center.x,self.scrollView.center.y-20);
self.plane.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_tag"].CGImage);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.plane];

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.path = self.trackPath.CGPath;
anim.duration = 320.;
[self.plane addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
self.plane.speed = 0.0;
self.plane.hidden = YES;
```

When Paging:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

    if((scrollView.contentOffset.x >= 320) && (scrollView.contentOffset.x<=640)){
        self.plane.hidden = NO;
        self.plane.timeOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x - 320;
    }
}
```