# How to animate sprite with fluent animation (change in form) in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I'm trying to work on the graphical aspect of a game I'm designing in Xcode using sprite kit, and I was wondering if anyone knows how the main character sprites in games like Leo's Fortune and Badland are animated when touched (they fluff up and morph very fluently). How could this be accomplished and what compatible file type could execute this fluent animation? Is .flv compatible with Xcode? I would rather not change the texture in a keyframe sort of way with a .png because that would require a lot of textures at a high texture switching rate.

Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: SpriteKit doesn't have any SKShapeNode tween functionality.  This question/answer might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858770/ios-cashape-layer-path-transformation/17864445#17864445 - but it's limited.  Frame based animations is likely your best route - imo

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @prototypical. I know that cocos2d was used in badland, would that possibly work better for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you know what they did in badland ? My impression is that they had frame based animations. Both spritekit and cocos2d are capable of animating textures. But ask a cocos2d specific question and maybe someone has shape tween/morph solution.